# Area of Coplanar Rectangle Segment From Line Intersection

Tags: math, computational-geometry

I know a lot of adjacent questions like this have been answered, but none match my current requirements.

I'm trying to determine the area of a polygon made by a coplanar rectangle-line intersection, using only the **below information**.

[Problem Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NIwJ.png)

Does anybody know of some way to determine the area of the segment (A1) based off the distance to the intersection line and angle between (r,u)? My intuition tells me there should be some some general function A1 = f(d,r,u,c), similar to
(https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html) but everything i've found seems to rely on finding the points where the line segments intersect. The env. i'm using only has trig functions, and no linear algebra modules, so some predefined function would make a world of difference...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a linear algebra module to do line-line intersection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection).

Comment: Sorry, should probably have explained my reasoning better. I get that, but i'm doing this for CFD, where each 'rectangle' is a boundary cell face and this has to occur at the start of each timestep and can't be parallelised. This means every single operation I do for each cell increases costs quite a bit.

My intuition was there has to be some sort of function for A1 that involves the angle between vec(r) and vec(u), along with d that would be a lot better than finding the intersection points of 4 line segments.

Comment: Is line l guaranteed to intersect any side of the rectangle?  If so: Which?

Comment: @flynnhack: whatever the way to handle this, the computation will amount to obtaining the points of intersection. The challenge is to simplify as much as can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Let `c` be the cosine of the angle between `r` and `u`, and `s` the sine. In a frame centered at `C` and aligned with `r`, the equation of the line is

```
s.X - c.Y = d
```

It intersects the lines `X=±W/2` and `Y=±L/2` at the points

```
X = (d ± c.L/2) / s, Y=±L/2
```

and

```
Y = (± s.W/2 - d) / c, X=±W/2
```

If you draw `s` from `c` as `±√(1-c²)`, you see that the functional relation between `c` and the sides of the triangle or trapezoid to be removed is an algebraic fraction. So the function after which you are is a piecewise algebraic fraction of the cosine. You can delimit the pieces by finding the critical angles, i.e. those for which the line passes through a corner. They respond to the equations

```
± s.W ± c.L = 2d
```

There are eight solutions (see below); knowing `c` (and the sign of `s`), they quickly tell you which sides will be intersected. You can do all computations with the four basic operations and the square root.

[image]

Comment: Legend, something along these lines is what I was thinking. Have to do some thinking to understand it properly but this helps.